# Rails 5.1 ActionController::UrlGenerationError in... No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

So, I was trying something today and I encountered this error. I created the views through scaffolding and it's associated model. I made some slight edits in the controller, but I can't figure this out and keep getting this error.

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in E#index
No route matches {:action=>"show", :b_id=>#<C id: 1, 
b_id: 1, ...>, :controller=>"d", :c_id=>#
<D id: 1, ...}, missing required keys: [:id]`
```

I have a few model associations, and I only encounter this issue when I am in the index view. I am able to create the object, I just can't display them in the Index.

Models

```
User.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :bs
  has_many :cs, through: :bs
  has_many :ds, through: :cs
end

B.rb
class B < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :companies, through: :users, as: :company_users
  has_many :cs, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ds, through: :cs
end

C.rb
class C < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bs
  has_many :ds
  has_many :companies, through: :bs, source: :company_users
end

D.rb
class D < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ds
  has_many :companies, through: :cs, source: :company_users
end
```

Controller

```
class DController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_d, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /appointments
  # GET /appointments.json
  def index
    @d = b_c.ds
  end

  # GET /d/1
  # GET /d/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /d/new
  def new
    @d = c.ds.new
  end

  # GET /d/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /d
  # POST /d.json
  def create
    @d = c.ds.new(d_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @d.save
        format.html { redirect_to [b, c, @d], notice: 'D was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @d }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @d.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /d/1
  # PATCH/PUT /d/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @d.update(d_params)
        format.html { redirect_to [c, @d], notice: 'D was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @D }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @d.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /d/1
  # DELETE /d/1.json
  def destroy
    @d.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to ds_url, notice: 'D was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_appointment
      @d = D.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def appointment_params
      params.require(:d).permit(:name, :phone, :start_time, :end_time, :c_id)
    end

    def c
      @c ||= C.find(params[:c_id])
    end

    def b
      @b ||= B.find(params[:b_id])
    end
end
```

And finally the Index view.

```
index.html.erb
...
<% @d.each do |d| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= d.name %></td>
        <td><%= d.phone %></td>
        <td><%= d.start_time %></td>
        <td><%= d.end_time %></td>
        <td><%= d.c %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', b_c_d_path(@b_c, d) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_b_c_d_path(@b_c, d) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', b_c_d_path(@b_c, d), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
...
```

Comment: You've abbreviated your variable names to the point of illegibility here. What is `redirect_to [b, c, @d]` supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSWER: I saw where my error was. I looked at rake routes and saw that I had to add .id to my arguments on the path. E.G. @b.id, @c.id. and then on the controller I defined them like so.

```
def index
  @b = b
  @c = C
  @d = b.find(params[:b_id]).c.find(params[:c_id]).d.all
end
```

Comment: That should be `index`, lower-case `i`. By convention variable and method names should not have any upper-case letters.